# How to load a txt file in MVC 5 respecting indentation and feed lines?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to load a text file in MCV5, I saw this piece of code works well

```
  public ActionResult ReleaseNotes()
 { var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/ReleaseNotes.txt"));
return Content(fileContents);  }
```

but I get something like:

> Fixed an error in the user information tool introduced in 3.7.3--------------------------v 03.07.03--------------------------- Change 'Last Logon' to 'Last Connection' in the top right navigation web menu- Disable Shared Configuration admin page, when Shared Configuration feature is deactivated

instead of respecting the indentation and the feed lines of the original format

> Fixed an error in the user information tool introduced in 3.7.3
>
> --------------------------v 03.07.03---------------------------
>
> Change 'Last Logon' to 'Last Connection' in the top right navigation web menu- Disable Shared Configuration admin page, when Shared Configuration feature is deactivated.

I have tried many solutions like:

```
public string ReleaseNotes()
    {
        string line,returnline="";

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(@"~\App_Data\ReleaseNotes.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            returnline = returnline + line + "\t\n";
        file.Close();
        return returnline;}
```

Do you know if there is a special class that manages only text files and respects the original format ?

thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify the controller and the view using a ViewBag to export the datas like that

In the controller

```
            string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"your file txt");
        var fileLines = new List<string>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            fileLines.Add(line);
        ViewBag.File = fileLines;
        return View();
```

In the View (cshtml file)

```
@{
string line;
foreach (var item in ViewBag.File)
{
    <p>@item</p>
}}
```

It should work properly

Comment: Thank you very much it works, I just have an error doing  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"your file txt");  I must put the whole path to accede to the file  and not the relative path and I don't know why?

Comment: You can find the solution in an other post, you must use the method 'MapPath()' first, to recovery the relative path before injecting it to  the StreamReader or StreamWriter like that:
    
 var path = Server.MapPath(@"~/your file");

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path, true);